# How to separate the dart board from the background with OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-segmentation

I use python and openCV. I would like to separate the dart board from the background. I tried it with findContours and Canny edge detection but I couldn't make it.

Example image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grab-cut` algorithm -

What you have to do is to specify the area of the image which'll act as a foreground as a rectangle. The algorithm will take a lil bit of time, and will throw out your required image... Code here requires a lil bit of tweaking though.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
#a is your image
img = cv2.imread('a.jpg')
mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2],np.uint8)

bgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
fgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)

rect = (360,85,1670, 1900)
cv2.grabCut(img,mask,rect,bgdModel,fgdModel,5,cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)

mask2 = np.where((mask==2)|(mask==0),0,1).astype('uint8')
img = img*mask2[:,:,np.newaxis]

cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

The final result in the source will give you a better result(after applying some masks)... But as I said you can modify it according to your wants.

[image]
Sources -

http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d8/d83/tutorial_py_grabcut.html#gsc.tab=0

Comment: One way is to resize the image before applying grab-cut...., it'll reduce the image size, thus reducing the algorithm running time.

Comment: Size does not matter, it keeps exiting after a few seconds (force close)

Comment: I edited the answer. I managed to get that image without any tweaking.

Comment: Than I think I have a problem with my computer